# transform raw query with subqueries to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following working query with a subquery which works fine I would like to transfrom to Eloquent because I would like persevere other relaiont of my User model

```
select * from (
select p.from, a.account_id, count(*) as num
from accounts as a
inner join accounts_prop as p on (a.account_id = p.account_id)
group by p.account_id 
having num = 1 ) query

where year(query.von) = 2017
```

I already have a User model represented by (`accounts` table) and a Property model represented by (`properites` table)

`User -> Property` relation is one to many

**User**

```
public function properties()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'account_id', 'account_id');
}
```

**Property**

```
  public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'account_id');
    }
```

The output should give back all users which have one Property and property matches current date.

In my raw query for testing purposes I was using constant year

Comment: Please post your table structure and post your expected output of query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually seems to work like

```
User::whereHas('properties', function($query){

            $query = $query->where('von', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
                           ->havingRaw('count(account_id) = 1')
                           ->with('department');

        })->get();
```